# ScriptAlias configuration not working in apache2

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, ubuntu-10.04, cgi-bin

I installed apache2 on ubuntu. I added the following to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file

`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/PROJECT/cgi-bin/"`

I am able to open the cgi file if i copy the cgi file to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`[DocumentRoot directory] and access the URL `http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`, but i get cannot access the file if i put it in `/home/PROJECT/cgi-bin/hello.cgi` even though `ScriptAlias` is set and apache2 restarted.

Any thing that i am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The reason was in httpd.conf, I had to remove global

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

otherwise everything starting /cgi-bin/ fell into /var/www/cgi-bin/.